# Creating a directory from one server to the next

Tags: python, linux, server

I am using Python to create a directory remotely from one server to the next. My code entails:

```
executedString = "sudo ssh -i mykey.pem server_ip %s" % (name_of_directory)
os.popen(executedString)
```

I also tried `os.system()` but that didn't work. The funny thing is that, when I run this through the terminal it works. However, when I executed it from my Python script, it doesn't.

I ensured that all the files were owned by the same user group and that didn't help.

Please note that I am also running this via CGI which is where code does not get executed even though the rest of the code works otherwise.

Please advise.

Comment: Where's the part where it tries to create a directory?

Comment: It should actually contain mkdir -p %s... as shown below.                                                                                                             executedString = "sudo ssh -i mykey.pem server_ip mkdir -p %s" % (directory_name)

Answer (score 1):

I realized it was an authentication key host issue when printed out all the logs of the ssh activity. The solution to this problem was that I copied the ~/.ssh  to /root directory.

I can only presume that either the key was not present in root or it was looking for auth key in root since only root can run the group/user owned by www-data.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your executing a shell to a UNIX host via a PIPE.  I'm thinking your command line should be the following:

```
executedString = "sudo ssh -i mykey.pem server_ip **mkdir** %s" % (directory_name)
```

Comment: The actual string I am trying to execute contains "sudo ssh -i mykey.pem server_ip mkdir -p %s" % (directory_name). It just doesn't create the directory when I execute it as is.

Comment: You stated above that your code runs find from the terminal, I assume that is the terminal of the machine the CGI is running from.  I assume this is running under apache.  If so apache's group permission is normally read only.  Can you pull a ls -la from the directory that you are looking to mkdir and determine if the uid of the web server has permissions to write.  Send the output if you can.

Comment: Thank you for  your response tknightowl. I am not quite sure I understand what you are asking. I am not calling mkdir in the terminal I am working. mkdir is called on the remote server. However, when I called mkdir on the remote server, the directory is not created from the python script but calling it from the terminal works using the string I posted earlier. The file that has the script is owned by www-data and the user group is the same. -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 7710 Nov 13 20:01 mkdir.py

Comment: I believe you need to have the 'x' bit set on the directory for the user to allow the creation of a directory

Comment: carefully perform a chmod u+x . <-- (notice the period) in the directory you want the directory to be created.

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work.  Server 1 is where I have the executable code and Server 2 is where I want to create the directory. From server 1 terminal it creates the directory on Server 2, however when I run it through the CGI it doesn't work. The CGI works ok because it does everything else correct inclusive of transferring files to dropbox so I know it is a permission issues. I just don't know how to solve it. I change the executable file to be owned by www-data but that doesn't work. I don't think I should make any change on Server 2. Should I?